# How to run curl command from python-need to press ENTER to exit

Tags: python, json

from BASH this works fine:,it searches JIRA and export results in JSON file

```
curl -XN -u user:Pass -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://jira.company.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project='"Technology"+AND+summary~"Remove%20User*"+AND+issuetype="Task"+AND+status!="DONE"' | python -m json.tool > /var/lib/rundeck/1.json
```

How to run same command from python

Tried this:

```
  #!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import re
import requests
import subprocess
import os
import urllib2


def bash_command(cmd):
   subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')


bash_command("curl -XN -u user:Pass -X GET -H \"Content-Type:application/json\" https://jira.company.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project='\"Technology\"+AND+summary~\"Remove%20User*\"+AND+issuetype=\"Task\"+AND+status!=\"DONE\"' | python -m json.tool > /var/lib/rundeck/1.json")
```

I got output,same as from BASH, but script is "stuck", it won't exit,file is created,it exits only when i press ENTER

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  9204    0  9204    0     0  47480      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 47443
```

added `sys.exit()` but same

tried this also,but no result:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False, ,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

exit()
```

Comment: try : process = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) 
stdout, stderr = process.communicate() or use import urllib2 to request the same

Comment: @Shivkumarkondi, it worked, just added `import urllib2` to original code, but how to "exit" it now, need to pres enter ?

Comment: Using an external process to fetch a web page is weird and inefficient. Just use `requests` to fetch it in native Python code.

Comment: can you post example ?

Comment: @Milister yeah posted the  sample  answer for you..let me know if that works for you

Comment: `cmd = 'curl -XN -u user:Pass https://jira.company.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project='"Technology"+AND+summary~"Remove%20User*"+AND+issuetype="Task"+AND+status!="DONE"' -o 1.json'` - Invalid-Syntax

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing on escape \ for quotes

`curlCmd = <your curl command, use escape for quotes like -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" >`

`curlRes = subprocess.check_output(curlCmd, shell=True).strip()`

Comment: `def bash_command(cmd):
 curlRes = subprocess.check_output(bash_command, shell=True).strip()


bash_command(/bin/curl -XN -u user:Pass -X GET -H \"Content-Type:application/json\" https://jira.company.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project='"Technology"+AND+summary~"Remove%20User*"+AND+issuetype="Task"+AND+status!="DONE"' | python -m json.tool > /var/lib/rundeck/1.json)` and got syntax error  under `="Done"`

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess

curlCmd = "curl -XN -u user:pass -X GET -H \"Content-Type:application/json\" \'https://jira.company.com/rest/api/2/search\?jql=project=\"Technology\"+AND+summary\~\"Remove\%20User\*\"+AND+issuetype=\"Task\"+AND+status!=\"DONE\"\' | python -m json.tools > /tmp/1.json"
curlRes = subprocess.check_output(curlCmd, shell=True).strip()
`
I tried this and no syntax error observed

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working,it exits without problems,thank everyone !1:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import re
import requests
import subprocess
import os
import urllib2


#def bash_command(cmd):
  # subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
   command=("curl -XN -u user:pass -X GET -H \"Content-Type:application/json\" https://jira.company.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project='\"Technology\"+AND+summary~\"%20User*\"+AND+issuetype=\"Task\"+AND+status!=\"DONE\"' | python -m json.tool > /var/lib/rundeck/1.json")

p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash' ,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

out, err = p.communicate()
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are reading some data from Jira page and writing it to a local file...is it so?

If so, better go for normal way to fetching data using GET request from Urllib and then write that data to required file

For that

```
output = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.somewebsite.com').read()
#write to file
```

And if you still want to use curl, then check the output data properly and dump the data to the file

I tried this simple step and it worked:

```
import os
cmd = 'curl https://randomuser.me/api/ -o  myoutput.json'
os.system(cmd)
```